# Question about the lifting of an arbitrary map to a covering space.

Tags: algebraic-topology, covering-spaces

> Let ($\tilde{X}$,$p$) be a Covering Space of $X$, $Y$ a connected and locally arcwise-connected Space, $y_{0}\in Y$, $\tilde{x}_{0}\in\tilde{X}$, and $x_{0}=p(\tilde{x}_{0})$. Given a map $\phi : (Y,y_{0})\rightarrow (X,x_{0})$, there exists a lifting $\tilde{\phi} : (Y,y_{0})\rightarrow (\tilde{X},\tilde{x}_{0})$ if and only if $\phi_{*} (\pi_{1}(Y,y_{0}))\subset p_{*}(\pi_{1}(\tilde{X},\tilde{x}_{0}))$.

I have a problem to prove that this condiction is sufficient. In particular, we define $\tilde{\phi}(y)$ as the final point of a lifting of $\phi\circ f$, where $f$ if a path in $Y$ from $y_{0}$ to $y$. I understood that this definition is well defined, but I have some problems to prove that $\tilde{\phi}$ is continuous. The proof says:

> let $U$ an arbitrary neighborhood of $\tilde{\phi}(y)$; choose an elementary neighborhood $U'$ of $p\circ\tilde{\phi}(y)=\phi(y)$ such that $U'\subset p(U)$. Let $W$ be the arc component of $p^{-1}(U')$ which contains $\tilde{\phi}(y)$, and let $U''$ be an elementary neighborhood of $\phi(y)$ such that $U''\subset p(U\cap W)$. It's clear that the arc component of $p^{-1}(U'')$ which contains $\tilde{\phi}(y)$ is contained in $U$. Because $\phi$ is continuous, we can choose $V$ such that $\phi(V)\subset U''$. We can also choose $V$ arcwise connected for the hypotesis. So $\tilde{\phi}(V)\subset U$ and $\tilde{\phi}$ is continuous.

I don't get why $\tilde{\phi}(V)\subset U$. Can someone help me? Thanks before!

Comment: I did not look at it in detail, but I think something like this should work: $V$ is arcwise connected, hence so is its image under $\phi$ and therefore also $p^{-1}(\phi(V)) \subseteq p^{-1}(U'')$ is arcwise connected ($p$ is a local homeomorphism). Hence $\tilde{\phi}(V) \subseteq  p^{-1}(\phi(V))$ is contained in the arc component of $p^{-1}(U'')$ which contains $\tilde{\phi}(y)$, hence it is contained in $U$

Comment: I don't see why $\tilde{\phi}(V)\subseteq p^{-1}(\phi(V))$

Comment: I guess you have a typo - it should be: Let $W$ be the arc component of $p^{-1}(U')$ which contains $\tilde{\phi}(y)$.

Comment: @user782709 because $\tilde{\phi}$ is a lifting of $\phi$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If one only reads the part of the proof presented in your question, it is indeed not very clear. The essential point is the *construction* of $\tilde \phi$. Usually (and I guess also in  your textbook) for each $y \in Y$ a path $u$ is chosen in $Y$ such that $u(0) = y_0, u(1) = y$. The path $\phi \circ u : I \to X$ starts at $x_0 = \phi(y_0)$ and ends at $\phi(y)$. This path has unique lift $l_u : I \to \tilde X$ such that $l_u(0) = \tilde x_0$. Now define $\tilde \phi(y) = l_u(1) \in p^{-1}(\phi(y))$. The condition $\phi_{*} (\pi_{1}(Y,y_{0}))\subset p_{*}(\pi_{1}(\tilde{X},\tilde{x}_{0}))$ is then used to show that this does not depend on the choice of $u$. This produces a function $\tilde \phi : Y \to \tilde X$ such that $p \circ \tilde \phi = \phi$.

Why is it continuous? The above construction shows the following:

We have $\tilde \phi (y) = l_u(1)$ for some path $u$ from $y_0$ to $y$. If $y' \in V$, we may choose a path $v$ in $V$ from $y$ to $y'$. Then $u * v$ is a path from $y_0$ to $y'$ ($*$ denotes composition of paths). The path $\phi \circ v$ is a path in $U''$ which starts at $\phi(y)$ and ends at $\phi(y')$. It has a unique lift $l_v : I \to \tilde X$ such that $l_v(0) = \tilde \phi(y)$. The set $l_v(I)$ is an arc connected subset of $p^{−1}(U'')$, hence it must be contained in the arc component $V$ of $p^{−1}(U'')$ which contains $\tilde \phi(y)$. We thus get $l_v(I) \subset V \subset U$. But $l_u  * l_v$ is a lift of $(\phi \circ u) * (\phi \circ v) = \phi \circ (u * v)$ such that $l(0) = \tilde x_0$. Thus $l_u  * l_v = l_{u*v}$ and therefore
$$\tilde \phi(y') =  l_{u*v}(1) = l_v(1) \in U .$$

Comment: So, the strategy is: If I fake a neighborhood V of y we have that there exsists $l_{v}$ lifts for each path from $y_{0}$ to $y'\in V$ so they go in the same arc component of $p^{-1}(U'')$ which is contained in U. So $\tilde{\phi}(V)\subset U$. Right?

Comment: If I take a neighborhood*

Comment: @user782709 Yes, that is correct.

Comment: Ok, now I see it. Thank you!